# R5RS circular dependency (cycle in loading)

Tags: file, scheme, r5rs

I have two `r5rs` files - `scheme-interpreter.scm` and `scheme-interpreter-operations.scm`. The first file contains two functions - `interpret` and `evaluate`. The second file contains auxilliary functions, which get called inside `evaluate`. However, these functions can call `evaluate` as well. Thus, recursion occurs. When I reference each file in the other one like this:

- `scheme-interpreter.scm`:

```lisp
(#%require "scheme-interpreter-operations.scm")
(#%provide (all-defined))
```

- `scheme-interpreter-operations.scm`:

```lisp
#lang r5rs
(#%require "scheme-interpreter-operations.scm")
(#%provide (all-defined))
```

I get errors. Is it possible to load files in a circular manner?

Comment: You're using Racket, right?

Comment: I am using `DrRacket` IDE. As for the language dialect, I try to stick to the `R5RS` standard as much as possible but `racket` could also do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Racket R5RS language with the racket module system on top like in your sample code, it's possible to have circular dependencies using using [`lazy-require`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/lazy-require.html).

Example:

s1.scm:

```lisp
#lang r5rs

(#%require "s2.scm")
(#%provide (all-defined))

(define (evaluate x)
  (cond
   ((and (pair? x) (eq? (car x) '+))
    (add (cdr x)))
   ((number? x) x)))

(display (evaluate '(+ 1 2)))
(newline)
```

s2.scm:

```lisp
#lang r5rs

(#%require racket/lazy-require)
(lazy-require ("s1.scm" (evaluate))) ; Lazily import evaluate
(#%provide (all-defined))

(define (add x)
  (apply + (map evaluate x)))
```

And demonstration:

```bash
$ racket s1.scm
3
```

For a general R5RS approach, a `(load "s2.scm")` in s1.scm works with Chicken, Guile and plt-r5rs, at least (With the Racket specific stuff removed, of course). Adjust filenames appropriately.